# R: Mapping unique columns of matching elements in 2 matrices

Tags: r

I am trying to map matching columns between 2 matrices.  For simplicity, I have 2 simple matrices, a and b:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
b <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2,3:8), nrow = 2, ncol = 5)

> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2

> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    2    4    6    8
```

I want to create a vector of length length(a[, 1]) = 2, ie

```
> out
[1] 1 2
```

Where the first element of out is the column number in b that matches the first column of a, and the second element of out is the column number in b that matches the second column in a.  I have tried

```
> match(data.frame(a), data.frame(b))
[1] 1 1
```

but I need each element of the resulting vector to be unique.  Probably simple solution, but I am not seeing it.  Thanks!

Comment: In your example, the 1st column of b (and 2nd column) match both the 1st and 2nd column of a. How do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: In numerical order.  First one it runs across first, second one second, etc.  I'm trying to avoid using any loops, so I hope there is a version of match() that would work

Comment: Same expected output.  First matching column in out element 1, second matching element in out element 2.  Any other matching columns would be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like `intersect`.

```
a <- matrix(c(10, 20), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
b <- matrix(c(10,20,1,2,3:6,10,20), nrow = 2, ncol = 5)

#> b
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   10    1    3    5   10
#[2,]   20    2    4    6   20

#Finding matching columns in b from a. Only 1st column of a is considered
matched <- b[,1:ncol(b)] == a[,1:1]

#> matched
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]
#[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#[2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE

desired <- which(matched[1,], arr.ind = TRUE)
#> desired 
#[1] 1 5
```

The matched column 1 and 5 are returned.

Comment: Intersect only matches the elements.  1 and 2 are the matching elements, but I am looking for the column numbers of b that correspond to the matching columns between a and b.

Comment: > a <- matrix(c(10, 20), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
+ b <- matrix(c(10,20,10,20,3:8), nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
+ intersect(a,b)
[1] 10 20

Comment: In the above code, I still want out as [1] 1 2, not [1] 10 20

Comment: @SeanSinykin Okay. Your requirement is now clear. Otherwise based on description in OP it seems you wanted matching value of column

Comment: @SeanSinykin Modified answer based on additional info from you. The `b` has been modified too in order to bring clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm not allowed to comment on here. Anyhoo...the above answer by MKR looks good, but I would add this line before creating the "desired" object. This is to ensure every column element matches (instead of testing the first row only).

```
matched<-sapply(1:ncol(matched),function(x) all(matched[,x]))
```